# Interaction of Themes, background colors, and Action bar

Tags: java, android, colors, themes

I am failing to understand the mode of interaction between the appearance of action bar and and thematization.  My app is set to use the default theme, which I take to be dark:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme">
</style>
```

Removing the action bar from the app via app-wide style results in black background for the main activity:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.atlarge.motionlog.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    >
```

Without the `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` line, the activity background is white.  If the action bar is removed in code in `onCreate()` method of the activity, the action bar is also gone, but the background remains white:

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();
```

**TL;DR:** Summary of behavior:

- Action bar present: white background
- Action bar removed via code: white background
- Action bar removed via XML: black background

Why is that?  Can someone explain (or point to a good resource) on the interaction of appearance of action bar via code vs. XML and the background color?

Answer (score 2):

Removing the action bar in the onCreate is just hiding the ActionBar view. 
It is not changing the theme.

Setting `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` is setting a theme to your activity which comes with any inherited styles in that theme hierarchy.

If you take a look at [themes.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml) in the android source, you'll see that in the style `<style name="Theme">` theres the item `<item name="colorBackground">@android:color/background_dark</item>`

Then `<style name="Theme.NoTitleBar">` which inherits all the styles of `Theme` sets `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>`

Then `<style name="Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">` which inherits from `NoTitleBar` and `Theme` sets `<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>` and `<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>`

which explains why you have a dark background when applying that style.

If you set your theme to `Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen` you'd achieve the same effect but you'd inherit `<item name="colorBackground">@android:color/background_light</item>` from `<style name="Theme.Light">` which should be a light color.

Alternatively, you can extend any them you want and override any of the styles.

so, for example, you could do something like...

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="colorBackground">@color/my_light_color</item>
    <item name="windowBackground">@drawable/screen_background_selector_light</item>
</style>
```

Here are some resources that might help you understand themes a bit more:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html
http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/understanding-android-themes-and-styles/

And if you want to create or extend your own themes, its always worth looking at the android source to see what you can extend and override:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#PlatformStyles

Hope that helps.